How should I show that $A(\eta)$ satisfies the equation $2\frac{dA}{d\eta}+2A^3\bar{A}^2-A=0$?
Homework problem: Consider the modified van der Pol equation $\ddot{x}+\epsilon(x^4-1)\dot{x}+x=0, 0<\epsilon<<1$, with initial conditions $x(0)=a$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$, where $a$ is a constant. By writing $X(t, \eta)$ in the form $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}(t, \eta)+\epsilon X_{1}(t, \eta)+O(\epsilon^2)$, derive the partial differential equations satisfied by $X_{0}(t, \eta)$ and $X_{1}(t, \eta)$, stating clearly the initial conditions for each case. Show that the solution to the equation for $X_{0}(t, \eta)$ can be expressed as $X_{0}(t, \eta)=A(\eta)e^{it}+\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$, where $A(\eta)$ is a function of $\eta$ only, $\bar{A}(\eta)$ is its complex conjugate, and the initial values are given as $A(0)=\bar{A}(0)=\frac{1}{2}a$. From the equation for $X_{1}$ derived, show that $A(\eta)$ satisfies the equation $2\frac{dA}{d\eta}+2A^3\bar{A}^2-A=0$. By writing $A=p^{1/2}e^{i\alpha}$, where $p$ and $\alpha$ are real functions of $\eta$, show that $\frac{dp}{d\eta}=p(1-2p^2)$ and $\frac{d\alpha}{d\eta}=0$.
Here's my work: Proof:
Consider the modified van der Pol equation $\ddot{x}+\epsilon(x^4-1)\dot{x}+x=0$ for $0<\epsilon<<1$, with initial conditions $x(0)=a$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$, where $a$ is a constant.
Applying the method of multiple scales, note that the solution to this equation can be written in the form $x(t)=X(t, \eta)$ with $\eta=\epsilon t$, where $X(t, \eta)$ satisfies the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial t^2}+X+\epsilon(2\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial\eta\partial t}+(X^4-1)\frac{\partial X}{\partial t})+\epsilon^2(\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial\eta^2}+(X^4-1)\frac{\partial X}{\partial\eta})=0,$ with initial conditions $X(0, 0)=a$ and $\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}(0, 0)+\epsilon\frac{\partial X}{\partial\eta}(0, 0)=0$.
By writing $X(t, \eta)$ in the form of $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}(t, \eta)+\epsilon X_{1}(t, \eta)+O(\epsilon^2)$ and equating the coefficients of the powers of $\epsilon$ to zero, we get $\frac{\partial^2 X_{0}}{\partial t^2}+X_{0}=0$ for $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}(t, \eta)$ in the zeroth-order equation $O(1)$.
Hence, the auxiliary equation is $\lambda^2+1=0\implies\lambda=\pm i$ and the appropriate solution for $X_{0}(t, \eta)$ can be expressed as $X_{0}(t, \eta)=A(\eta)e^{it}+\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$, where $A(\eta)$ is a function of $\eta$ only, $\bar{A}(\eta)$ is its complex conjugate.
Similarly, we have $\frac{\partial^2 X_{1}}{\partial t^2}+X_{1}=-2\frac{\partial^2 X_{0}}{\partial\eta\partial t}-(X_{0}^{4}-1)\frac{\partial X_{0}}{\partial t}$ for $X(t, \eta)=X_{0}+\epsilon X_{1}$ in the first-order equation $O(\epsilon)$.
Since $X_{0}(t, \eta)=A(\eta)e^{it}+\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$, it follows that $\frac{\partial X_{0}}{\partial t}=iA(\eta)e^{it}-i\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 X_{0}}{\partial t^2}=-A(\eta)e^{it}-\bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$.
From the initial condition of $X(0, 0)=a\implies X_{0}(0, 0)=a$, we have $A(0)+\bar{A}(0)=a$.
My question is, how should I derive the equation for $X_{1}$ from here and show that $A(\eta)$ satisfies the equation $2\frac{dA}{d\eta}+2A^3\bar{A}^2-A=0$? Also, how should I show that $A(0)=\bar{A}(0)=\frac{1}{2}a$?

I am not familiar with the relevant theory, so I tried to find a simple and natural reason leading to the equation for $A(\eta)$. After substituting $X_0 = A(\eta)e^{it} + \bar{A}(\eta)e^{-it}$, the equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 X_1}{\partial t^2} + X_1 = -2\frac{\partial^2X_0}{\partial\eta\partial t}-(X_0^4-1)\frac{\partial X_0}{\partial t}
$$
takes the following form
$$
\frac{\partial^2 X_1}{\partial t^2} + X_1 = \sum_n B_ne^{int}\tag{eq}
$$
with
$$
B_1 = -i\left(2\frac{\partial A}{\partial\eta} + 2A^3\bar{A}^2 - A\right),\quad B_{-1} = \bar{B}_1.
$$
If the right-hand side of equation (eq) contains terms proportional to $e^{\pm it}$, then the solution $X_1$ will contain growing terms proportional to $te^{\pm it}$, which is unacceptable in perturbation theory. Therefore, it is natural to require that $B_1 = 0$, which yields an equation for $A(\eta)$.
About initial conditions. From
$$
x(0) = X_0(0,0) + \epsilon X_1(0,0)+\ldots = a,
$$
$$
\dot{x}(0) = \frac{\partial X_0}{\partial t}(0,0) + \epsilon\left(\frac{\partial X_0}{\partial\eta}(0,0) + \frac{\partial X_1}{\partial t}(0,0)\right)+\ldots = 0
$$
it follows that
$$
X_0(0,0) = a,\quad \frac{\partial X_0}{\partial t}(0,0) = 0\tag{ic0}
$$
and
$$
X_1(0,0) = 0,\quad \frac{\partial X_1}{\partial t}(0,0) = -\frac{\partial X_0}{\partial\eta}(0,0)\tag{ic1}
$$
Given that $X_0(t,\eta) = A(\eta)e^{it} + \bar{A}(t,\eta)e^{-it}$, the initial conditions (ic$0$) lead to $A(0) = \bar{A}(0) = \frac{a}2$. Knowing $A(0)$, you can calculate the initial conditions for $X_1$ (ic$1$).

What about the fact that $A(0)=\bar{A}(0)=\frac{1}{2}a$? How should I show/prove this? And from the very first question, it asks to derive the partial differential equations satisfied by $X_{0}(t, \eta)$ with $X_{1}(t, \eta)$, what should $X_{1}(t, \eta)$ be? Is it just $\frac{\partial^2 X_{1}}{\partial t^2}+X_{1}=-2\frac{\partial^2 X_{0}}{\partial\eta\partial t}-(X_{0}^{4}-1)\frac{\partial X_{0}}{\partial t}$?

Yes, I think the equation for $X_1$ is the one you derived. As for the initial conditions, I updated the answer.

Everything is clear now. Thank you very much for your help!
